# In Laura Esquivel's book "Como agua para chocolate" this phrase appears

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Qué significa la siguiente frase?

> Observar lo repuesta que se encontraba Chencha

Comment: Ey, Frank, welcome to the site. Have you looked the words contained in the phrase in a dictionary? Do you have any specific problem with any of those words? Some of the sites in StackExchange, like this one, require some previous work or investigation. That sentence can be translated as "Check how recovered Chencha was"